# Need help understanding data-stream processing tradeoffs

Tags: stream, iterator, dataflow, gnuradio

I would like to implement a dataflow-based system for digital signal processing, much like [GNU Radio](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki), where processing occurs in blocks, and these blocks are strung together to process a stream of data. As far as I can tell, there are three ways to pass around the stream of data: A block can "push" data to the next block, a block can "pull" data from the previous block, or blocks can process buffers of data and return buffers of data, with a scheduler handling the buffers (this last way is the way GNU Radio operates).

There are trade-offs with each approach. For example, the "pulling" architecture requires, for a block that takes one input stream and returns two output streams, that the output streams be buffered with an arbitrarily large buffer (the second output could be "pulled" for `n` samples before the first output is pulled). Similarly, the "pushing" approach has the same problem with blocks that take 2 input streams and return 1 output stream. But I would argue that both of these methods make block implementation easier, since each block can view their inputs and outputs as one stream.

Before I get any further with the project, I'd like to know: Has there been research into the tradeoffs between the different ways of implementing flow-graphs like this? I would really like a write-up that I can read so that I understand the issues before running into them half-way through implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is an incredibly broad question. You could definitely read a lot of books to form a really well-informed opinion on the matter at hand.

However, pulling doesn't exist in the world of general purpose OS'es. You can have two things

1. polling, where your downstream block constantly asks "is there new data yet?", which is wasteful and generally is considered bad design
2. waiting, which lets your downstream block's thread wait until the scheduler or the a neighbouring block notifies him of change (ie. there's new data available, or your downstream block is now ready to process more data, so you can produce some)

GNU Radio does 2., which scales well, is easy to multithread and therefore works excellently on SMP architectures. I've written a really small, really basic [intro](http://gsoc.hostalia.de/posts/a-measurement-toolbox-for-gnu-radio-my-google-summer-of-code-project.html#evaluating-block-performance) into how the GNU Radio scheduling mechanism works, but there is also some information linked from http://gnuradio.org